# Compare values in two columns

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012, sql-like

I need help in returning values in a query.  Consider my example below where the values in Column A are linked to Column B:

```
Column A             Column B
---------            ---------
45008                AQZ45008D
45008                ABC12345
45007                45007AX
45007                11652019
45007                JMD45007
```

All I need is to return rows where values in Column A are found somewhere in Column B.  So in this example, rows 1, 3, and 5 would need to be returned.

I hope this was a clear example.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: [What have you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com)? Please post the query and explain where you are stuck.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try:

```
SELECT *
FROM Table
WHERE ColumnB LIKE '%' + ColumnA + '%'
```

I am assuming that these two columns are varchar. Otherwise you may need to CAST them.

Comment: +1 Could also use `WHERE CHARINDEX(ColumnA , ColumnB) > 0` if any danger of `ColumnA` containing characters of significance in the pattern syntax.

Comment: Thanks this works.  I started with the code but, had the columns reversed and was missing the majority of the data.  Appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you want the values to match in parallel, which would be easiest, but if any value of `ColumnB` can be matched with any value of `ColumnA`

Try using:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ColumnA
FROM Table t
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT TOP 1 ColumnB FROM table t2 WHERE t2.ColumnB LIKE '%' + t.ColumnA + '%')
```